# What are some alternatives to PersistentPerl or SpeedyCGI?

Tags: perl

I like [PersistentPerl](http://daemoninc.com/PersistentPerl/) quite a bit for both web and command-line use. The only problem is it keeps me tied down to Perl 5.8.x, as it's apparently no longer maintained. I'm aware of mod_perl and FastCGI, but these don't appear to have CLI functionality (correct me if I'm wrong!). So is there a suitable replacement for PersistentPerl?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but you might find the answers to this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410939/how-can-i-improve-moose-performance-in-non-persistent-cgi-processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[App::Persistent](http://github.com/jrockway/app-persistent) is the modern alternative.  It is kind of beta and requires a Haskell compiler, but it is very fast and very non-magical.  It tends to Just Work.

Example persistent application: http://github.com/jrockway/app-persistent/blob/master/repl.pl

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know I would recommend FastCGI for your problem, it's just a process that sits there handling requests. You don't have to put a web front-end on it. mod_perl would be the same sort of thing. Your script turns into a service around which you have a thin wrapper. Again, it depends on what you are doing.